# Quickstart 4.3.2 "Bad Request", "messageCode":"XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND", "message":"XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts.jsonPropertyReference(\"id\")

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Ive been working through this tutorial  https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/tutorial/4x/harmonize-order-data-by-custom-code/   and have followed it exactly as per the tutorial.

The server is a dev machine that was built clean from the ground up on Windows 2016 with latest Microsoft required patches on it. The MarkLogic server 9.0-8.2 is empty apart from the tutorial data ( imported from the downloaded ML-provided zip file ). I have also downloaded the latest version of the 4.3.2 quickstart from https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/releases/tag/v4.3.2  but this has not fixed the issue. I have ensured a base URI has been included in each entity.

The issue is the harmonization of the Orders data which fails within 1 second and generates the error below in the quickstart output window ( I also tried the 4.1.1 quickstart - same result.)

I have also tried using gradle 5.x to manually install the data hub etc, but get the same problem every single time which is frustrating.

I found this possible fix ( https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/issues/705 ), but it doesnt work.

I have tried with element range index on and off on the Orders entity, but this made no difference.

This is the error I get when trying to run harmonization. The job fails almost immediately. Harmonization of Customers and Products is fine. Upgrading to a higher version of data hub or quickstart is not an option at the moment.

Any help appreciated.

```
2021-05-30 14:33:57.111 ERROR 3504 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.rest.util.MgmtResponseErrorHandler   : Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":400, "status":"Bad Request", "messageCode":"XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND", "message":"XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts.jsonPropertyReference(\"id\") -- No  element range index for id collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/ coordinate-system=wgs84"}}
14:33:57.111 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR c.m.r.util.MgmtResponseErrorHandler - Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":400, "status":"Bad Request", "messageCode":"XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND", "message":"XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts.jsonPropertyReference(\"id\") -- No  element range index for id collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/ coordinate-system=wgs84"}}
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
        at com.marklogic.rest.util.MgmtResponseErrorHandler.handleError(MgmtResponseErrorHandler.java:26)
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:766)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:698)
        at com.marklogic.hub.collector.impl.CollectorImpl.run(CollectorImpl.java:151)
        at com.marklogic.hub.flow.impl.FlowRunnerImpl.run(FlowRunnerImpl.java:187)
        at com.marklogic.quickstart.service.FlowManagerService.runFlow(FlowManagerService.java:113)
        at com.marklogic.quickstart.web.EntitiesController.runHarmonizeFlow(EntitiesController.java:164)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$510f8b9a.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
        at com.marklogic.quickstart.auth.ConnectionAuthenticationFilter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c59083e0.doFilter(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: "Fixed with the following PR: #939 For now, we are making the tutorial align with how the QuickStart and DHF work. Which is to have the primary key and element range index decoupled. A user will have to set both the primary key and an element range index on Order id to complete the tutorial, which is what others describe in comments above."  Have you attempted to create the element-range index on `id`?

Comment: Hi Mads, in DH 4.1.1, no range element index was in the Orders entity in Quickstart.In the Staging db I added index via Databases/Range Element Indexes GUI admin page, scalar type "string", namespace URI as < blank >, localname as "id" , collation as "marklogic.com/collation" , range value positions as "true", invalid values as "reject". No joy, keep getting same error. I loaded the Orders data from the 4.x tutorial supplied store-data.zip file so everything is 100% unchanged from the tutorial. But in 4.3.2 it works OK. Both 411 & 432 DHs installed by quickstart ( no internet connection ).